# Converting UCS-2 encoded file to ANSI encoding in Windows Mobile 5/6

Tags: encoding, file-conversion, pocket-pc

I would need to be able to convert UCS-2 encoded a text file to ANSI (or ISO8859-1) on Windows Mobile 5 and 6 platforms, and to make it even harder, it should be something that is scriptable (i.e. possible to call from SymScript with parameters to perform the conversion). I know I'm asking a lot but desperate times call for desperate solutions...

The scenario here is to do modifications on a config file on a number of devices. There's Soti Mobicontrol deployed on the devices so pushing the required stuff to devices is no issue, and the devices have SymScript interpreter available so I have rather nice scripting environment, but as far as I know, SymScript lacks a command for reading non-ANSI encoded files and the file to be modified seems to be UCS-2 little endian with BOM...

If there is a free-to-use scripting environment other than SymScript that I could use, I would be glad to know of it, too.

Answer (score 0):

Since what I was asking started to seem like impossible to do, I ended up trying to sync the config files from the devices using Soti file sync rules (files from each device to individual folder, luckily that is possible to do). Then I could use whatever desktop (scripting) tool to convert those files, and finally use a similar file sync rule to push the edited files back to the devices (storing the converted file in different location on the device so that it won't get overwritten).

This isn't really a good answer for the question posed in the question title, so it might not work for anyone else having similar situation...